# Figure not properly placed overlaps text

Tags: floats, positioning

I am having problems inserting a figure in my LaTeX file. Here is the code that I use

```
\begin{figure}[hbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=20mm, height=20mm]{Wheatstone.jpg}
\caption{Wheatstone's Stereoscope.}
\label{fig:cclogo}
\end{figure}
```

All I want is that the image should come below the text and be properly centered. Right now it comes on  the side of the text. Maybe I am doing something wrong with the placement?

Comment: The problem you described is not to be expected in normal circumstances. Can you please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the odd bahaviour described?

Comment: Are you still faced with this problem?